# Angular: ValueChanges not fired for FormControl

Tags: angular, forms

I have a form with 2 dropdowns for filtering.

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Equipment Class</mat-label>
        <mat-select FormControlName="equipmentClass">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let class of equipmentService.equipmentClasses" [value]="class">
                {{class.description}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngIf="true">
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Equipment </mat-label>
            <mat-select FormControlName="equipment">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let equipment of equipmentService.equipments" [value]="equipment">
                    {{equipment.description}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-button (click)="newEquipment()">Create New</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The formGroup is declared in my controller as such:

```
filterForm = new FormGroup({
  equipmentClass: new FormControl(''),
  equipment: new FormControl(''),
});
```

I want to listen for changes on both dropdowns. So in `ngOnInit` I am subscribing to the `valueChanges` emitter of both formControls.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.filterForm.get('equipmentClass').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
  this.filterForm.get('equipment').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

However, the values are never logged as the function is never called when the user makes a selection in the dropdown.

It seems I have done everything [according to the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).
Any help is greatly appreciated as this is my first time working with ReactiveForms.

Comment: Your code looks good, not sure what is going wrong here. Can you try making a stackblitz ?

Comment: Do you have the `ReactiveFormsModule` included in your module?

Comment: very obvious issue, you're putting  `FormControlName` instead of `formControlName`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez Thanks a bunch .. (slightly emberrased :-) )